# Creating a (temp?) table that is accessible only in the current connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, security

I want to enforce row-level security for ***any*** client connecting to a particular SQL Server database (just one database). I don't want to impose any particular set up required to happen on the client side (because this would mean that a client can set up itself so that it would have access to anything - which of course would be bad; BTW, the client is a WinApp that connects using either Windows Auth or SQL Auth). I basically want this to be transparent to any client. The client should not even know this is happening.

The enforcement of the row level security will be performed in views inside the database that are layered above the tables (in essence: no one will have the ability to perform DML against the tables directly; instead, all operations shall be performed against the views that lay on top of the tables. These views will have instead-of triggers running under a particular 'execute as', to ensure the DML operations can be correctly executed).

So basically, I want to remove the potential of the client to circumvent this security model by baking it into the database itself.
I also want to separate out the permissions granted to the user from the effective permissions that are applied to the current connection (think of it this way: if you are connected to the DB, you have a Security Context associated with your connection - maintained in the DB, mind you - this Security Context contains the information about which items you have access to. Upon establishing the connection, this Security Context is created and populated with information based of the permissions assigned to you and when the connection is closed, the information in this Security Context is removed; in fact, the entire Security Context should be removed). Of course, the Security Context should only be available within a given connection, connections should not have the ability to even see the existence of a security context for other connections.

*(EDIT: one of the scenarios explicitly targeted, which explains why the Security Context is separated from the 'defined permissions' is as follows: if you establish a connection to the DB, you get a SecContext; now while your connection is active/not closed, the admin assigns new permissions to you, these new permissions will not be applied to this currently open connection. You must close the connection and re-establish a connection to have these changes reflected in your SecContext)*

I know how I can enforce that the views will only return information that the user has access to. That's the easy part... This question is about creation and deletion of the Security Context I am talking about.

- The Security Context should be created on establishing the connection.
- It should also reside in an artifact that is accessible only to the current connection.
- It must be queryable during the lifespan of the connection by the connecting user.
- Finally, the Security Context must be dropped/removed/deleted when the connection is closed.

Would anyone have an idea about how this can be achieved.

Thanks

Comment: Oracle has a "virtual private database" feature that intercepts all DML and silently/transparently appends a WHERE-CLAUSE that implements the security policy.  The where-clause references one or more columns in the table/view, filtering out rows the user should not see.

If you are going to be using views in SQL Server, you must be intending to rely upon the values in one or more columns to create your "filtered" view of the data.  I follow up to that point.  But I don't follow how you intend to map the permissions found in the Security Context to the views.

Comment: What about instead of having a temp table for each individual user, have a single persistent Security Context table shared for all users, with an additional column to specify the user... which also has some type of row level security applied to it.

Answer (score 2):

A SQL Server temp table (one with a name starting with #) is only available to the current connection, and dropped at the end. You only have to deal with establishing it on creating a new connection.

However it sounds like you are re-implementing a lot of what the DBMS already does for you. I would recommend reading up more on SQL Server's built-in security mechanisms, in particular login/user/schema separation.

Comment: Hi Artbristol,Thanks for the reply; however, although SQL allows for artifact level security (e.g. access to a table/view or even access to a column in a particular table); it does not provide an implementation for row level security (i.e. you're allowed to see rows 10 -> 100 but not rows 1 -> 10). It is this row level security that I am trying to implement.

The problem with the temp table is: it must be created on logon, which means I need a server-wide logon trigger. However, temp tables created in that logon trigger are not available in the connection of the logged on user)

Comment: So basically that's my question: how do I create this temp table (and populate it - that's easy though) in such a way that the logged on user has access to it

Comment: OK, sounds like you know a fair bit more than me :-) I'd either wait for MS to implement row-level security themselves, or enforce access to the DB through a layer of stored procs rather than views (at least partially generated to avoid copy/paste) which can create the said table at the start, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your application in the abstract, so I don't entirely understand where you're coming from here, but here's a question for you: it sounds like you're giving your users a direct connection to your database.  Do you need to do that?

Perhaps I'm missing the point, but could not all of this row-level security be done away with entirely if you built into your application an API, rather than provided your users with a direct database connection?  If you set things up that way, your API could be the gatekeeper which prevents users from making changes to rows to which they should not be given access.  Perhaps that would be simpler than working directly at the database level?

I hope that's helpful.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the reply. You are correct, I am providing a direct connection to the database. The application for this is a reporting warehouse and so it is impossible to provide an API since all reporting tools connect to the DB directly (e.g. Excel, SSRS, etc...). By implementing this in the API, we open ourselves up for anyone who *can* connect to the DB to circumvent the security implementation by just not using the API (think: rogue employee with any tool that can connect to the DB, connecting to the DB outside of the application to see stuff (s)he is not allowed to see).

Comment: By implementing security in the DB itself, the connecting client ALWAYS plays by the security rules of the DB and cannot circumvent them. (defense in depth)

Comment: That makes perfect sense, @potentis. I'm afraid I'm in over my head at this point, but for what it's worth, I stumbled onto a reference to this book recently.  Perhaps it would be helpful? http://amzn.to/iejnhV